# Using Wildcards in the Prefix of Thymeleaf's Template Resolver

Tags: spring, thymeleaf

I am trying to set up Thymeleaf so that it will search all the subpackages in my classpath for template files (e.g. `my.root.package.subpackage1`, `my.root.package.subpackage2`, `my.root.package.subpackage3`).

My configuration looks like this:

```
@Bean
public ThymeleafViewResolver viewResolver() {
    final ThymeleafViewResolver resolver = new ThymeleafViewResolver();
    resolver.setTemplateEngine(templateEngine());
    resolver.setCharacterEncoding("UTF-8");
    return resolver;
}

@Bean
public SpringTemplateEngine templateEngine() {
    final SpringTemplateEngine engine = new SpringTemplateEngine();
    engine.setTemplateResolver(templateResolver());
    return engine;
}

@Bean
public SpringResourceTemplateResolver templateResolver() {
    final SpringResourceTemplateResolver resolver = new SpringResourceTemplateResolver();
    resolver.setApplicationContext(context);
    resolver.setPrefix("classpath:my/root/package/**/");
    resolver.setSuffix(".html");
    resolver.setTemplateMode(TemplateMode.HTML);
    return resolver;
}
```

But this is throwing an exception:

```
Java.io.FileNotFoundException: class path resource [my/root/package/**/Example.html] cannot be opened because it does not exist
    org.springframework.core.io.ClassPathResource.getInputStream(ClassPathResource.java:172)
    org.thymeleaf.spring4.templateresource.SpringResourceTemplateResource.reader(SpringResourceTemplateResource.java:103)
    org.thymeleaf.templateparser.markup.AbstractMarkupTemplateParser.parse(AbstractMarkupTemplateParser.java:226)
    org.thymeleaf.templateparser.markup.AbstractMarkupTemplateParser.parseStandalone(AbstractMarkupTemplateParser.java:100)
    org.thymeleaf.engine.TemplateManager.parseAndProcess(TemplateManager.java:662)
    org.thymeleaf.TemplateEngine.process(TemplateEngine.java:1089)
    org.thymeleaf.TemplateEngine.process(TemplateEngine.java:1063)
    org.thymeleaf.spring4.view.ThymeleafView.renderFragment(ThymeleafView.java:335)
    org.thymeleaf.spring4.view.ThymeleafView.render(ThymeleafView.java:189)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.render(DispatcherServlet.java:1243)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.processDispatchResult(DispatcherServlet.java:1027)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:971)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:893)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:968)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doGet(FrameworkServlet.java:859)
    javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:622)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.service(FrameworkServlet.java:844)
    javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:729)
    org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:52)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.resource.ResourceUrlEncodingFilter.doFilterInternal(ResourceUrlEncodingFilter.java:52)
    org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107)
```

It doesn't seem to like the wildcard. It works just fine if I hard-code the subpackage.

Any ideas why this doesn't work?